# Enable keyboard Shrink view for android

Tags: cordova, meteor

Currently I'm using ["cordova-plugin-keyboard@1.2.0"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard) plugin to shrink the keyboard but it doesn't support android devices.

Is there any other plugin which I can use?